# Debugging Rails 3 using RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine to develop a Rails3 application, but I cannot manage to get the debugger working. I always get the following message:

> Cannot connect to the debugged process
>   at port 60706 in 10s:
>
> Dumping and destroying process, when
>   the debuggee process is running. You
>   might try to increase the timeout.
>   Killing...
>
> Error Output:  Fast Debugger
>   (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta3,
>   ruby-debug-base 0.11.26) listens on
>   127.0.0.1:60706
>
> Please try increasing timeout in
>   Settings | Debugger | Ruby | Debug
>   connection timeout

I have of course tried to increase the timeout value, but that does not help. I have no idea how to approache the problem. I cannot see any debug output, error log, ... Any hint would be very appreachiated!

Answer (score 2):

It now works for me, with

- RubyMine 3.1.1 build 103.260
- ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta5
- ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25  (I'm not sure wether or not this is actually used)

It didn't work with *.beta3* for me, but works like a charm now (*.beta5*)

Comment: The build number of my RubyMine is the same and I updated tha ruby-debug-ide gem from beta3 to beta5. But it does not help!?

Comment: hmm, what attached gems do you have. list those starting with ruby-debug. Try cleanup and attach the gems above. You need the `ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)` in your `gem list` too.

Comment: Have the same issue, I did not found it sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with RubyMine 5.4 ([RubyMine 5.4 debugger times out, but debug console shows connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185113/rubymine-5-4-debugger-times-out-but-debug-console-shows-connected)) no indication of any errors, but the debug connection always timed out.   Manual remote debugging on the local system worked, however.   It turns out that on my system (Mac OS X 10.8.3) that `hostname` returned `localhost`.   Running `sudo hostname new-name` solved the problem and now RubyMine internal debugger works just fine.