# Cannot connect to debugger in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I'm getting this error when trying to run the debugger on RubyMine.

```
Could not connect to Debugger

Cannot connect to the debugged process at port 51452 in 10s:  Local process: RubyDebugTarget[baseDir: null, debuggedFile: /Users/myUser/RubymineProjects/untitled1/main.rb, port: 51452, remote: false, process: com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess@3833471d, process alive: true] Please try increasing the timeout in Settings | Debugger | Ruby | Debug connection timeout
```

I am currently using RubyMine 2023.2 but have also tried the 2022 and 2021 versions and they yield the same error. I also checked that Ruby and RubyMine allows for incoming connections in the firewall settings.

My configurations:

RubyMine 2023.2

macOS Sonoma

debase 3.0.0.beta.6

ruby-debug-ide 3.0.0.beta.10

Ruby 3.1.4

For reference, I ran a project on IntelliJ and PyCharm and the debugger runs fine for these two IDEs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Raise the ticket there and they would resolve your problem.

Comment: It's worth checking if VPN or corporate Wi-Fi are in use. For example. there was a thread with VPN blocking the connections (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185113/rubymine-5-4-debugger-times-out-but-debug-console-shows-connected/72894357#72894357 )

Comment: How did you fix it?